# WPF emended ItemTemplateSelector in a DataTemplates

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

Hey there I am new to WPF and I have a project where I want to use an ItemTemplate selector inside a DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PicTemp">
...
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:key="MsgTemp">
...
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:key="PuttingItTogether">
<TextBlock Text="HeaderText" />
???<ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource Select Either PicTemp or MsgTemp>}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

In the third Data Template how can I setup a template selctor to choose either the PicTemp or MsgTem DataTempalte?

Answer (score 1):

[ItemTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx) is a property of an ItemsControl. You need to apply a style to the ItemsControl in order to set it. And you need to set it to an instance *of an ItemTemplateSelector subclass* that contains logic to return the appropriate DataTemplate for each item in the ItemsControl based on some property of the item.

I [found](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector) this tutorial useful for learning how to correctly implement a DTS.

Answer (score 0):

An [ItemsTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx) is used for ItemsControl such as ListBox, ListView and ItemsPresenter.
It can be used to select a DataTemplate based on the items source object. However in most cases, it is more easy to specify the [DataType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype.aspx)-property of the corresponding DataTemplate.

In your example I don't see how exactly you want to use the TemplateSelector, since you don't have an `ItemsControl`.